# C# : Passing Parameters to a function via a 2d object array

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to write a neat little generic Sql method that will accept a SQL Query and a list of parameters, and return a result. I want to keep it neat enough that I can call it using one line from any other code.

Is there any really awesomely neat way of doing this? I don't want to create all the SqlParameters in the calling code, and I don't want to have to pass and split a string. In the past I've used a string[] array and accepted every odd member as a parameter name and every even as a param value but that's too easy to screw up when calling the method.

Ideally I'd love to do just this:

```
Data.SQL("Select * from Table where my_id = @my_id", { my_id = 1 });
```

I know that's a little unrealistic, So I tried this:

```
Data.SQL("Select * from Table where my_id = @my_id", new Object[,]{ { "my_id", 1 } });
```

However when I try and handle that on the other end, I get nothing but trouble:

```
public static Object SQL(String command, Object[,] parameters = null){
     [ ... reusable SQL code here... ] 

     foreach(Object[] p in parameters){
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(p[0].ToString(), p[1].ToString());
     }
}
```

Looks fine, but throws an error on the foreach statement

```
foreach (Object[] p in parameters)
```

***Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object[]'***

But I *didn't pass* it an array of System.String. What I *passed* was a 2D System.Object[]! Wasn't it?

Maybe this is just some small code problem, something stupid I'm doing wrong. It usually is. But I'm figuring you guys know some even neater way to do the above.

Comment: Any reason you're not using a dictionary for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ideally I'd love to do just this:
>
> ```
> Data.SQL("Select * from Table where my_id = @my_id", { my_id = 1 });
> ```
>
> I know that's a little unrealistic,

Well, in *exactly* that form, yes... but try this instead:

```
Data.SQL("Select * from Table where my_id = @my_id", new { my_id = 1 });
```

That will use an *anonymous type* for the argument, which you can examine by reflection. You probably only need a single parameter (i.e. it would be `SQL(string sql, object parameters)`) because you would pass multiple parameters in a single object:

```
Data.SQL("Select * from Table where my_id = @my_id and name = @name",
         new { my_id = 1, name = "Jon" });
```

More alternatives:

- If you're using C# 4, you might find dynamic typing useful; look at what [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) does for example.
- As mentioned by Ray, you could pass in a `Dictionary<string, object>`; again, C# 3 makes this easier than otherwise:

  ```
  Data.SQL("...", new Dictionary<string, object> { 
           { "my_id", 1 },
           { "name", "Jon" }});
  ```

---

EDIT: As for the exact problem you're running into: you need to understand the difference between a *rectangular* array (e.g. `Object[,]`) and a *jagged* array (e.g. `Object[][]`). The latter is an array of arrays, which is how you're trying to *use* the parameter, but it's really only a rectangular array. Changing your parameter type to `Object[][]` may well fix that immediate problem - but personally I'd move to one of the approaches above. I'd also try to *avoid* making everything into a string, by the way.

Comment: Would you really recommend an anonymous type and reflection for the sake of a bit simpler calling syntax?

Comment: @Ray: It partly depends on how often this is used. The reflection code can all be in one place, but making the calling syntax simpler could make the code more readable all over the place. That's why having lots of different options is good :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm going to try the anonymous type approach and have the dictionary method to fall back on!